# How to display all sheet name in combobox | excel vba |

Tags: excel, vba

I have a scenario where i want to display all the sheet name in combobox

On Main sheet i have one dropdown combobox

this combobox should display all the sheet names present in excel

output :

```
Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3
.
.
.
```

**How to modify this below code to get all sheet name in combobox**

```
Private Sub ComboBoxpgname_DropButtonClick()

    With Worksheets("A1")
                ComboBoxpgname.List = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
Private Sub ComboBoxpgname_DropButtonClick()
Dim sh As Worksheet

    ComboBoxpgname.Clear 'Clear combobox
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ComboBoxpgname.AddItem sh.Name
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: can you please provide solution to this post also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60138221/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-combobox-excel-vba

Comment: First if this answer solve your problem then consider the answer as accepted. Tick it as green.