# How to populate unique values into combobox?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to populate unique values into combobox.

*My sheet details*
[image: Sheet]

**Code:**

```vb
Private Sub ComboBoxscname_DropButtonClick()
    With Worksheets("A1")
                ComboBoxscname.List = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

I have highlighted with yellow which are duplicated for column "B" and should be displayed only once in combobox.

Another solution I have but getting error when selecting specific sheet name.

```vb
Sub ComboBoxscnameList()

Dim LR As Long
Dim ctrl As Object
'Set ctrl = Sheets("A1").Select

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

ctrl.List() = CreateArray(Range("B2:B" & LR))

End Sub

'creates an array from a given range
'ignores blanks and duplicates

Function CreateArray(r As Range)
    Dim col As New Collection, c As Range, TempArray(), i As Long

    'for each cell in range r
    For Each c In r
        On Error Resume Next
        col.Add c.Value, CStr(c.Value)
        If Err.Number = 0 And Trim(c) <> "" Then
            ReDim Preserve TempArray(i)
            TempArray(i) = c.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
        Err.Clear
    Next

    CreateArray = TempArray
    Erase TempArray

End Function

Private Sub ComboBoxscname_DropButtonClick()
Call ComboBoxscnameList            
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to save a unique set of values from a `Column` or `Range` is by using a `Dictionary`. You loop though your cells in column B, and check if each one is already in the `Dictionary` keys, the syntax is `Dict.Exists("your_parameters")`.

You can read more about using `Dictionary` [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object).

Review the modified code below, you want to add it to your `UserForm_Initialize()` event.

***Modified Code***

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


Dim i As Long, ArrIndex As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim Dict As Object, Key As Variant
Dim HSNArr() As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' us a Dictionary, and save unique Eco-System as array
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' <-- modify to your sheet's name
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim HSNArr(1 To LastRow) ' redim HSN array >> will optimize size later
    ArrIndex = 1

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Not Dict.Exists(.Range("B" & i).Value2) And Trim(.Range("B" & i).Value2) <> "" Then  ' make sure not in Dictionary and ignore empty cells
            Dict.Add .Range("B" & i).Value2, .Range("B" & i).Value2 ' add current HSN
            HSNArr(ArrIndex) = .Range("B" & i).Value2
            ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With
ReDim Preserve HSNArr(1 To ArrIndex - 1) ' resize to populated size of Array

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

With Me.ComboBoxscname
    .Clear ' clear previous combo-box contents
    For i = 1 To UBound(HSNArr) ' loop through array, add each unique HSN to Combo-Box
        .AddItem HSNArr(i)
    Next i

    ' show default value
    .Value = HSNArr(1)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: how to pass sheet name from variable to your code ... the sheet name is from another combobox ... below i added the code please look and suggest me how do i get selected page name from combobox to your code as input With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("pgname")

Comment: @jomen40544jmail7.com not sure I understand, what is the sheet's name ? or it's variable name ?